# Como pegar o numero do celular no ionic usando cordova ou phonegap

Tags: apache-cordova, ionic, ionic2

Estou desenvolvendo um app e preciso pegar o número do celular.
Pesquisei bastante na internet e não consegui achar muita coisa.
Um dos exemplos que eu encontrei foi esse: [cordova-plugin-sim](https://github.com/pbakondy/cordova-plugin-sim) mas não consegui fazer ele retornar o número. Segue um exemplo do meu código:

```js
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.controller('mainController', ['$scope','$cordovaGeolocation','$interval',function ($scope,$cordovaGeolocation,$interval) {

  $scope.geolocation = function() {
    $interval(function(){
        var geoSettings = {frequency: 30000, timeout: 100000,enableHighAccuracy: false};
        var geo = $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSettings);
        geo.then(function (position) {
                $scope.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                $scope.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                console.log($scope.latitude)
                console.log($scope.longitude)
            },
            function error(err) {
                $scope.errors = err;
            }
        );
    },3000);
  }
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">

    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
 document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
 function onDeviceReady(){
 window.plugins.sim.getSimInfo(successCallback, errorCallback);
 }
 function successCallback(result) {
 document.getElementById("simInfo").innerHTML=JSON.stringify(result);
 }
function errorCallback(error) {
 document.getElementById("simInfo").innerHTML=JSON.stringify(result);
 }
 </script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content ng-controller="mainController">
    <button class="button button-full button-assertive" ng-click="geolocation()">
    Localização
    </button>
    <sapn>Latitude: {{latitude}} </sapn>
    <br>
    <sapn>Longitude: {{longitude}} </sapn>
    <br>
    <sapn>Info: {{infoPhone}} </sapn>
    <p id="simInfo"></p>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei que versão do SDK você está usando mas apartir do 23 tem que pedir permissão para leitura.

`// Checar permissão
function hasReadPermission() {
  window.plugins.sim.hasReadPermission(successCallback, errorCallback);
}`

`// Pedir permissão
function requestReadPermission() {
  // no callbacks required as this opens a popup which returns async
  window.plugins.sim.requestReadPermission();
}`

Comment: Adicionei as permissões. Funcionou no meu emulador genymotion, mas não no celular. Estou testando pelo Ionic View, não sei se pode ser isso. Para fazer um teste mais preciso, vou gerar um apk e testar novamente para ver se funciona.

Comment: No final acabei não conseguindo obter o número em um celular específico. Pesquisei um pouco e descobri que alguns celulares não guardam o número no cartão SIM. Por esse motivo não foi possível resgatá-lo. Mas acredito que sua resposta deva resolver o problema para versões mais recentes e como eu ainda não estava usando isso, marquei ela como correta! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a própria [documentação do plugin](https://github.com/pbakondy/cordova-plugin-sim), o conteúdo que representa o número do telefone não é confiável, podendo retornar um string em branco (ou nulo):

"*Notice: the content of phoneNumber is unreliable (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6797278), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922734/getting-reliable-msisdn-from-android-phone-voicemailnumber-line1number), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25861064/retrieving-line1-number-from-telephonymanager-in-android) article). Sometimes phoneNumber is only an empty string.*"

Além disso, em alguns casos, pode até retornar um número antigo, que foi armazenado no SIM card previamente.

Pelo que li, o fato dessa informação estar presente no SIM card ou não (e de estar atualizada ou não), depedende até da operadora - algumas armazenam essa informação no SIM card, e outras não (fazendo tudo via rede).

Nos meus testes que fiz em um celular TIM, voltaram várias informações, mas não voltou o número do aparelho (sendo que pedi a permissão direitinho, como tem que ser feito a partir da versão 23). Quero em breve testar o mesmo código em outros celulares e com chips de outras operadoras.

Comment: Depois de alguns testes, vi que era isso msm. Na época ao testar em outros celulares funcionou. Ou seja, para alguns celulares ele retornava o número e para outros não. Então para não ter problemas, acabei mudando um pouco o aplicativo e fazendo com q o usuário informasse o número quando eu não conseguisse obtê-lo!

Comment: Acabei também fazendo a mesma coisa, pedindo pro usuário digitar o número, já que - pelo menos nos testes que consegui fazer - apenas SIM cards da Oi tinham essa informação (nos TIM e Vivo que testei, o número não era armazenado, provavelmente porque as operadoras pegam essa informação dinamicamente via rede de telefonia).

Comment: Além disso, decidi nem tentar verificar automaticamente antes de pedir pro usuário digitar, pois além dessa funcionalidade funcionar apenas pra uma minoria de usuários, seria outro plugin pra manter no app, além dele exigir uma permissão que pode parecer meio intrusiva pro usuário ("Permitir que o app ... faça e gerencie chamadas telefônicas").

Comment: Sim. Eu negaria essa permissão. Mas o projeto que estava fazendo era para uma empresa especifica e os usuários eram os funcionários q ja sabiam que teriam de fornecer essa informação e a sua localização para o app. No final eu fiquei muito satisfeito com o resultado. O desempenho e a praticidade em desenvolver com o IONIC e Cordova me surpreenderam bastante! :)